# Issue with event listener - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, event-listener

I am trying to make a dynamic program that will insert some number of buttons, and perform some action `onClick`.

So far, for my test example, I took 5 as a number of buttons and some message as event that will happen `onClick`. Problem is there is not any change when I click on any of buttons.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="C:\Users\milosn\Desktop\addlevel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body id="ide" onload="retrieveMultipleRecords()">
  <p id="ha">text</p>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is JS:

```
function retrieveMultipleRecords() {

  var d = document.createElement('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var b = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var t = document.createTextNode('TEXT');
    t.id = 'tek';
    b.appendChild(t);
    b.addEventListener("click", func);
    d.appendChild(b);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    d.appendChild(br);

  }
  document.body.appendChild(d);

  function func() {
    document.getElementById("ha").InnerHTML = "some other text";
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what error messages are you getting on your browsers developer tools console?

Comment: JS is case sensitive: `.InnerHTML` -> `innerHTML`

Comment: It works now, thanks!